# Unicode and urllib.open

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, urllib

I am creating an application in python that can parse weather data from [yr.no](http://yr.no) in Python. It works fine with regular ASCII strings, but fails when I use unicode.

```
def GetYRNOWeatherData(country, province, place):

    #Parse the XML file

    wtree = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen("http://www.yr.no/place/" + string.replace(country, ' ', '_').encode('utf-8') + "/" + string.replace(province, ' ', '_').encode('utf-8') + "/" + string.replace(place, ' ', '_').encode('utf-8') + "/forecast.xml"))
```

For example, when I try

```
GetYRNOWeatherData("France", "Île-de-France", "Paris")
```

I get this error

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xce' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is it true that urllib doesn't handle unicode very well? Since I am using Tkinter as a frontend to this function, would that be the source of the problem (does the Tkinter Entry widget handle unicode well?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by keeping every string as a `unicode` right up until you actually make the `urllib.urlopen` request, at which point you `encode` to `utf-8`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This import makes all literal strings in the file default to
# type 'unicode' rather than type 'str'. You don't need to use this,
# but you'd need to do u"France" instead of just "France" below, and
# everywhere else you have a string literal.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def do_format(*args):
    ret = []
    for arg in args:
        ret.append(arg.replace(" ", "_"))
    return ret 


def GetYRNOWeatherData(country, province, place):
    country, province, place = do_format(country, province, place)
    url = "http://www.yr.no/place/{}/{}/{}/forecast.xml".format(country, province, place)
    wtree = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen(url.encode('utf-8')))
    return wtree


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GetYRNOWeatherData("France", "Île-de-France", "Paris")
```

Comment: @Igor Sorry, I had reversed the positions of `province` and `place` when creating `url`. It should work properly if you swap them back (I just did so in an edit to the answer).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that as well. Thanks